# How to load start up screen (*GNU Emacs*) f it hasn't already been created?

Tags: emacsclient, start-up

When you run Emacs in daemon mode and then connect to it with emacsclient it doesn't show the start screen (`*GNU Emacs*`) but instead puts you into the `*scratch*` buffer, which is normally fine. But if I decide I want to see the start screen at some time, I can't just change the buffer to get into it because in daemon mode it seems it was never created in the first place. I'm sure there must be a function I can call with m-x, but I guess my emacs knowledge is still to low for me know what to search for to find it, because I haven't been able to find the answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange!  There is no one single function -- it is 43 lines of code inside `startup.el` -- excluding the calculation for the let-bound variable `displayable-buffers-len`.  So the answer will most likely be for someone to create an interactive function using those 43 lines of code, and to figure out what to do with `displayable-buffers-len`.

Comment: @lawlist It looks like it there actually is a function in `startup.el` named `fancy-startup-screen` which does this. (Emacs 24.5)  I'm surprised that this isn't one of the options included in the `C-h` prefix keymap.

Comment: @nispio -- thank you.  It's been so long since I created a custom `startup.el` that I didn't remember removing that function and making it entirely in-line.  I have one lengthy `normal-top-level` function that incorporates just about everything.  The optional argument `concise` is the calculation for `displayable-buffers-len`.

Comment: @nispio, Thanks for your research and your answer! It worked perfectly.

Comment: Another solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25218535/580010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following to your init will allow you to show the startup screen any time by pressing `C-h j`:

```
(defun show-fancy-startup-screen ()
  (interactive)
  (fancy-startup-screen))
(global-set-key "\C-hj" 'show-fancy-startup-screen)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the menu: `Help => About Emacs`, or you can use <kbd>C-h C-a</kbd>.

Comment: I accepted the previous answer because it answered the exact question I asked, but really this answer is just as good because the `*About GNU Emacs*` buffer your answer pulls up has all the same links, just in a different order, and it doesn't involve adding any new functions or keybindings. I wish I could accept more than one answer!